# Two side button display on a table

Tags: c#, winforms

I want automatically switch on / off electric appliances. So I want add two side button in `tableview` . How can do this?[image]

Comment: post what you have tried so far?

Comment: I was able to add only normal button for now.

Comment: What is two side button?

Comment: You need to use a toggle switch not a button.

Comment: @Nilesh  I want to add button like on the image

Comment: You could be sneaky and just use a CheckBox and set its appearance to Button.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.kettic.com/winforms_ui/csharp_guide/buttons_togglebutton.shtml) you may use `ToggleButton`. The `ToggleButton` for WinForms is designed to manage states on your .NET Windows Forms. It has similar functionality of the `CheckBox`. However, the `ToggleButton` control provides a different visual effect and more flexible stylish design than the standard `CheckBox` button. have a look at [`Windows Forms ToggleButton`](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/794577/Windows-Forms-ToggleButton) article from codeproject for more details and implementation.

Comment: Thank you for your response

Answer (score 1):

You could override how the button is drawn along with a Boolean value to hold the on/off state of the control. A quick ugly attempt that could be cleaned up with a little work is:

```
class OnOffButton : Button
{

    bool on = true;

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
        pevent.Graphics.Clear(this.BackColor);
        pevent.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, 0, 0, 85, 25);
        if (on)
        {
            pevent.Graphics.DrawString("ON", new Font("Microsoft sans serif", 8, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 5, 5);
            pevent.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Gray, 50, 1, 35, 24);
        }
        else
        {
            pevent.Graphics.DrawString("OFF", new Font("Microsoft sans serif", 8, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 50, 5);
            pevent.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Gray, 1, 1, 35, 24);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        on = !on;
        Invalidate();
    }

    public bool On { get { return on; } }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

> I want automatically switch on / off electric appliances. So I want
>   add two side button....

I assume you need a **[toggle switch control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465475.aspx)** :

[image]

The toggle switch mimics a physical switch that allows users to turn things on or off. The control has two states: on (checked is true) and off (checked is false).

**[How to add a toggle switch (XAML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868198.aspx)** :

```
<ToggleSwitch x:Name="toggleSwitch1" Header="ToggleSwitch" 
              OnContent="On" OffContent="Off" 
              Toggled="ToggleSwitch_Toggled"/>
```

You could find the toggleswitch in higher versions of .NET Framework .
Also there are several third party tools which provide the same.

If you have no other choice you can opt checkbox (Toggleswitch is derived from **checkbox** )

More reference :

[**toggle switch class**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.toggleswitch.aspx)

Thanks